# Querying a server level trigger definition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to query the definition text of a server-level trigger.  More specifically, trying to query the definition from within a user-defined stored procedure.  Because the trigger is saved on the server level, the normal ways do not seem to work.

**What I have tried:**

1)
`sp_helptext`: The scope is wrong and I get the message:

> Msg 15009, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 54
>   The object 'myTrigger' does not exist in database 'master' or is invalid for this operation.

---

2) `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'myTrigger)) AS ObjectDefinition;`:

This returns `NULL`.  I replaced "myTrigger" with the object id from `sys.server_triggers`.  This also returns `NULL`.

---

3)

```
SELECT
    name,
    s.Definition
FROM 
    sys.server_triggers t
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules  s
        ON t.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE name = 'myTrigger'
```

The object doesn't exist in `sys.sql_modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT ssmod.definition AS [Definition]
FROM master.sys.server_triggers AS tr
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.server_assembly_modules AS mod ON mod.object_id = tr.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_sql_modules AS ssmod ON ssmod.object_id = tr.object_id
WHERE (tr.parent_class = 100) and (tr.name = 'MyTriggerName')
```